# Unexpected newline error /bin/sh case statement

Tags: shell, scripting, debian, case, sh

Okay, so I seem to have exhausted the information which google can give me.

I have reduced my code down to a minimal broken example:

```
#!/bin/sh -xv
case "$1" in
    *)
        echo "usage";;
ecas
```

This (extremely) minimal code consistently produces the error:

> Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")

and points to the last line of my code.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error message and how to eliminate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misspelled `esac`.

Comment: Thankyou. I'm going to go and hide in a hole now.

Comment: Go find an editor that provides you with syntax highlighting. It would have made this mistake obvious. My I suggest VIM?

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to say **esac** instead of ecas!

Comment: +1 for truth, but unfortunately you were beaten to it by triplee